# Dynamic generation of hexadecimal coded data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following sequence is an escape sequence for a Bluetooth  printer, so that the printer could know that the string following this sequence should be encoded into a QR code.

```
[27, 90, 0, 2, 7, 23, 0]
```

This sequence should be encoded in hexadecimal string format :

```
let str = ''
str = str + "\x1b" + "\x5a" + "\x00" + "\x02" + "\x07" + "\x17" + "\x00"
```

Where each "\xab" value is the hexadecimal representation of each number presented in the sequence.

The "23" ("17" in hex) value, is the length of the text that should be encoded into QR, consequently, its value is dynamic, hence its hex value should be concatenated dynamically to 'str'.

Using string concatenation :

```
 str = ...etc... + "\x07" + "\x" + generateHex("23") (generateHex converts decimal value to Hex)
```

resulted in an error because "\x" expects a hexadecimal digit sticked to it.

Using a double backslash to escape "\x" did not work either (it was not interpreted as valid Hex value).

Your Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan Are you sure that comment is necessary? OP has their input, expected output, _and_ attempt (well, most of it) in their question.

Comment: @AKX Ok, the last part was important since we are missing the generateHex -- but it is a dupe in any case. But your answer is great

Answer (score 5):

Use [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) to turn those codepoints to their characters. The `String.fromCodePoint` function accepts a variable number of arguments, so you can actually just splat the array in:

```
> String.fromCodePoint(...[27, 90, 0, 2, 7, 23, 0])
'\x1BZ\x00\x02\x07\x17\x00'
```

Comment: I have an issue, 
String.fromCodePoint(90) will return 'Z', instead of "5A", I need the Hexadecimal representation of 90 and not the equivalent ASCII character

Comment: That is not an issue. The string still contains the byte represented by `\x5A` (0x5A, decimal 90), it just happens to be more succinctly represented as `Z`.

Comment: In other words, `'\x50\x49\x5a\x5a\x41\x21'` is the exact same string as `'PIZZA!'`, just represented differently.